# Turn SSL off in certain virtual directory

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess, ssl, https

I want to turn ssl off in a virtual directory - cron 
some urls that need to run via http are for example /cron/one , /cron/two or /cron/three

I'm using this rewrite to force ssl

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

some examples, here should ssl be turned off:

```
/cron/one
/cron/two
/cron/three
```

some help?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not possible to disable SSL for a given uri.
This is a chicken and egg problem. The channel is already encrypted when the client send the GET / POST HTTP method call to the server containing the requested URI.
SSL can be enabled or disabledw per virtual host with the **SSLEngine** directive.

You could create a dedicated virtual host in plain HTTP listening on 127.0.0.1 that handle your /cron/ URI, or you could use a HTTPS enabled CLI HTTP client from your crontab.

Comment: You may have misread the question; they are using `mod_rewrite` to force SSL across a site, and now they want to stop that rule from applying for a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your SSL VH:

```
Redirect /cron/one http://your.domain/cron/one
Redirect /cron/two http://your.domain/cron/two
Redirect /cron/three http://your.domain/cron/three
```

Which will re-direct those URLs to the NON-SSL VH.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! /cron/one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! /cron/two
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! /cron/three
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```